# Is it possible to properly format .php file containing php+html code using zend studio 13?

Tags: php, html, code-formatting, zend-studio

I am unable to format properly  php+html combined code in php file using zend studio, previously I have used net-beans IDE , it was good in that, but in my current organisation they are strict to use zend studio as IDE.
Below is a code snippet that shows after formatting using (Ctrl+Shift+F) standard formatting option of Zend studio. Also I have tried all possible inbuilt formatter of zend studio, but no success! :(

Your help will be appreciable.

```
<div class="col-md-6">

                                <?php

    echo form_element(DEPARTMENT_CATEGORY_NAME, 'select', 'department', array(
        'list' => $DataAllDepartmentsCategory,
        'text_field' => 'category_name',
        'list_before' => $cat_common_arr,
        'value_field' => 'dept_category_id',
        'selected' => $DataUser['department']
    ), 'medium', array(
        'validation' => array(
            array(
                'required',
                'true',
                VALIDATE_REQUIRED
            )
        ),
        'error_message' => $err['departmentError']
    ));

    ?></div>
```